# Deny User Agent in Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm being hit with a vulnerability probe which uses `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee` and I want to drop/reject any requests from that user agent.

I've been digging around the k8s examples but I can't seem to find a solution.

Is there any way I can deny requests based on `User-Agent` with `gcr.io/google_contianers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3`?

Comment: Why is your kubernetes exposed to the external world?

Comment: Huh? It's a service that's running via an AWS LoadBalancer.

Comment: Oh ok. Please look at this article https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-webserver-security.html and point #12

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'm not having trouble with that. I'm having trouble with configuring a rule where I want the request to be denied if the user-agent is from `Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee`

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell from [the nginx go-template](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/nginx-0.9.0-beta.13/controllers/nginx/rootfs/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl), that is not something the current implementation of their ingress controller offers. I believe that in their mental model, one would wish to do that kind of suppression in a per-`Service` manner, since doing it in the `Ingress` controller could very easily apply that rule to the whole cluster, leading to surprising outcomes for other published `Service`s. I took a look at [the haproxy controller's go-template](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/blob/v0.4-snapshot.4/rootfs/etc/haproxy/template/haproxy.tmpl) and it seems to be true there, also.

At this point, I think you have two options:

1. [Use a custom nginx go-template file](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/nginx-0.9.0-beta.13/examples/customization/custom-template/custom-template.yaml), which might not be "bad" but one will need to exercise caution when doing upgrades, since your controller will no longer come with a known-correct `nginx.tmpl`
2. Try [a more advanced haproxy ingress controller](https://github.com/appscode/voyager/blob/3.2.0/docs/user-guide/ingress/backend-rule.md), which allows you to specify arbitrary haproxy snippets right in your Ingress resource, which is the best approach I have seen thus far, modulo their `backendRule` array seems [not to be standard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#ingressbackend-v1beta1-extensions)

Answer (score 1):

you can add custom nginx configuration snippets to Ingresses with annotations, at least for the "normal" nginx controller, not sure if that works with the GCE controller too. See e.g. here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/examples/customization/configuration-snippets/nginx/ingress.yaml#L8